# How do I enforce Laravel one-to-one relationship in the child table?

Tags: laravel

I have "contacts" and "clients" tables, where "clients" is effectively an optional extension of the data in the "contacts" table. As far as the Laravel models go, I will use hasOne() and belongsTo(), no problem. In the migration class for clients, I have specified

`$table->foreign("contact_id")->references("id")->on("contacts");`

My question is, in order to ensure that each parent can have no more than one child, should I also add

`$table->unique("contact_id");`

I can find no documentation advising me to do this, but it seems intuitively right. Any observations?

Comment: no data duplication will occour, so same number can't fit (unique). while just with just foreign, clients may have multiple contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - a unique index on your database column is the way to ensure this integrity in the database. The Laravel documentation shows you how to use unique indexes (like you're using) but it's really your call whether you implement this restriction in your Laravel code or the database. Your Laravel app should be configured to not allow duplication, but the database constraint will give you absolute confidence (i.e. throw an exception when someone tries to insert an invalid record).